# Python plotly scatter_3d size

Tags: python, plotly-python

I'm trying to plot some points with the scatter_3d function but the plot get "elongated" along the z axis for some reason:

[image]

Is there a way to fix it? I tried to fix the size of the plot expected in to adjust but it doesn't seem to be the case. I plot it in the browser renderer.

```
pio.renderers.default='browser'

fig = px.scatter_3d(df_pmt, x='x', y='y', z='z',
                    color='Generation', size='Generation', size_max=18, opacity=0.9)
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=500
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Have a look at this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033791/plotly-same-scale-for-x-and-y-axis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it in the doc, it can be fixed by using "Fixed Ratio Axes":

`fig.update_layout(scene_aspectmode='cube')`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to adjust axis ranges. You can use the method [`update_layout`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.update_layout). For example:

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[0, 4], yaxis_range=[0, 4], zaxis_range=[0, 4])
```