# How can I set the axes to be squares (same scale) in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am plotting some data using dash plotly and my problem is that I want to make the scale of both X and Y the same.

A similar problem was asked but [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46895153/4451521) does not work for me. When I tried it, the scales were not the same (which is weird since the docs say that is how to do it)

Just in case the layout of my plot is as follows:

```
fig.update_layout(
    title='My Plot',
    xaxis_title='X-axis',
    yaxis_title='Y-axis',
    height=800, # this in order that the plot is not too flat
    showlegend=True,
    legend=dict(x=0.0, y=1.0, xanchor='left', yanchor='top'),  # Move the legend to the left
    )

    # Adjust the chart area to start to the right of the legend
    fig.update_xaxes(domain=[0.1, 1.0])

    fig.update_xaxes(minallowed=-1000,maxallowed=5200) #this is to avoid unused space inside the plot

    fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor="x",scaleratio=1,) #this did not work

    # fig.update_xaxes(scaleanchor='y', scaleratio=1)  # Set the X axis to have the same scale as the Y axis -> tried this too but it did not work
```

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same if the axis ranges were aligned? Add `range=[0,100]` to the settings for each axis; if the ranges of the x-axis and y-axis are different, add the width of the graph size.